# How can i convert a webpage into pdf/image by Page URL in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass a web page url to another aspx page and need to convert it into PDF or image format and save on specific path.

Comment: Are you looking for a paid software or a free one ?

Comment: You could try something with [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). Download the HTML file to your pc, then run Pandoc to convert it to HTML. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There are many web services where you could utilize their services and accomplish your tasks.

If you need a screen shot only, i would recommend you to use Selenium.

Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of libraries can do this, some are free, but most of them are commercial. Free version generally has some limitation. Check this:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Convert-HTML-to-PDF-with-C-b16fc75f

code reference:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using Spire.Pdf; 
using System.Threading; 

namespace HtmlToPDF 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            // create a pdf document. 
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); 

            String url = "http://www.e-iceblue.com/"; 
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => 
            { doc.LoadFromHTML(url, false, true, true); }); 
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); 
            thread.Start(); 
            thread.Join(); 

            // save pdf file. 
            doc.SaveToFile(@"..\..\sample.pdf"); 
            doc.Close(); 

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"..\..\sample.pdf"); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps.